# SASS partial import doesn't work in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, sass

I practice SASS coding invention now.
I made react app using `npx create-react-app`.

My structure is like below.

```
src
├── test
│   ├── _index.scss
│   utils
│   ├── _index.scss
│   └── _mixins.scss
│
├── main.scss
...
```

And I imported `scss` files in `main.scss`.

```css
@import "components";
@import "utils";
```

However, it causes error, and I have no idea what I did wrong.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/styles/main.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/styles/main.scss)
Module not found: Can't resolve './components' in '~/src/styles'
```

Comment: you don't have `components.scss` files ? Why are you declaring `@import "components";` ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé, `components` is folder name. I'm gonna make some component file styles in this folder and I tried to import the `components` folder in `main.scss`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I saw this article. https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

Comment: Comment out the import until there is a file to import.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo, I already tried to comment out `@import components` before. I made `_index.scss` file to import every `scss` files in `utils` folder, but it doesn't work well.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo, it occurs this error
`Module not found: Can't resolve './utils' in '~/src/styles'`

Comment: You need to import files, @import does not support folder import like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
@import "./utils/_index";
@import "./utils/_mixins";
```

You have to specify the relative path to the scss file or else your code will not work

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know this way. If you don't mind, could you check [this](https://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) out?
I saw this article, and I'm trying this

Comment: @MingyuJeon so what are you trying to ask ? Is my code working ?

Comment: Yeah, your code is working. What I meant was I know this already, but I wanted to try another way, like this [link](https://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import). This guy doesn't import with the path but just write the folder name.

Comment: Yes you can do that by default sass can import folder like that

Comment: @MingyuJeon if my question solve your problem please accepted my answer. Thank you

Comment: but why couldn't I import folders...? Your answer is the way to import files with absolute path

Comment: No you cant, you must provided the file name and the path for sass

Comment: Ok, Thank you! I thought there's a way.